# prestashop changing page icon doesn't work

Tags: php, prestashop

I am using Prestashop for the first time. I try to change icons in the default theme but the change doesn't reflect on the UI

E.g: in block contact info, I have originally

```
<li>
          <i class="icon-phone"></i>{l s='Call us now:' mod='blockcontactinfos'}
                    <span>{$blockcontactinfos_phone|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</span>
                </li>
```

I want to remove 
`<i class="icon-phone"></i>`
and add my own icon `<img src="\img\icons\call.png" />`

But the UI still look the same after I changed the code to

```
<li>
                    <!--<i class="icon-phone"></i>-->
                    <img src="\img\icons\call.png" />{l s='Call us now:' mod='blockcontactinfos'}
                    <span>{$blockcontactinfos_phone|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</span>
                </li>
```

I use chrome inspector and see that the source code doesn't change at all. How can I add my own icons in prestashop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because Prestashop uses 1) Module overrides and 2) Template cache system. You should disable cache memory in BO in Settings -> Performance and then clean the cache with the button on the top right. Next You need to edit:

not: **root/modules/blockcontactinfos/blockcontactinfos.tpl**

but **root/themes/yourthemename/modules/blockcontactinfos/blockcontactinfos.tpl** file.

This should help fix Your problems :)